# Is there a way to set the attribute name dynamically via sld substitution in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sld

In **Geoserver**, a have a **SLD** style with a rule that looks like this

```
    <Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:PropertyName>
                      property
                  </ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:Function>

                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>value1</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>

            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">
                    #ff0000
                </CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                    0.5
                </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
        </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

In the WMS request, i send an **env parameter**, specifing the `property` and the `value1` parameters for dynamic sld substitution. The `property` parameter gets a value of an attribute name that exists on the layer I want to display the style with.

My solution won't work. I get an **exception**, saying:

> The requested style cannot be used with this layer. The style
>   specifies an attribute property and the layer is: ...

Is there a way to **set the attribute name dynamically** via sld substitution in Geoserver? And if yes, how can I achive that?

I am using Geoserver 2.7.2

---

Btw. this works:

```
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>

                  <ogc:PropertyName>
                      Einwohner
                  </ogc:PropertyName>


                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>value1</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>

            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
```

Comment: does 
                  <ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Function name="env">
                      property
                  </ogc:Function></ogc:PropertyName> work?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, this would give a validation error:  `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Function'. No child element is expected at this point.`

Comment: I am starting thinking about creating a string for SLD_BODY on the fly, although I find it to be a little hacky. Should also be less perfomant, I guess.

Comment: Don't worry about validator, does it work?

Comment: No, it does not. The error is gone, the layer gets rendered, but the filter is not working as expected. In fact, no matter what value `value1` is, the filter now always includes all objects of the layer.

Answer (score 3):

I could not work this out. The feature of dynamically setting property names via env variables seems not to be supported at this moment.

I ended up with a different solution now (using the Geoserver REST API for styles) and I am quite happy with it.

Here is what I did: based on what the user enters on the GUI, I manually wrote sld (as a complete string). Then, I uploaded this string to the style REST endpoint of Geoserver, setting the correct content-header, as described here: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/rest/api/styles.html

Every style is getting a unique identifier. Before uploading a style, I try to download it via GET to see if it exists. If I get a 404, I do a POST to upload a new style. Otherwise, I upload my string with a PUT to modify the existing style. Once a style has been uploaded, I use the style Id in WMS GetMap requests.

Answer (score 1):

degisken1
                      GIS_ID
                  
                 [image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please always include code as text rather than pictures in your answers (and questions) so that it can become searchable and easy to copy for any testing.  There is a format button **`{}`** available to make it easy.

Comment: This answer saved my ass today.

Answer (score 1):

I had been use SLD programming for polygon fill might be it will help you,
have look my code,

```
    <Rule>
        <PolygonSymbolizer>
                <Fill>
                     <CssParameter name="fill">
                        <ogc:Function name="env">
                            <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>#E6E6E6</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                     </CssParameter>
                </Fill>
        </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe too late, but for whom this could be of any help, this is an example of a filter using variable substitution that worked for me:

```
       <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>agno</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>year</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>2010</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo> 
                <ogc:PropertyName>mes</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>month</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

Then, in the WMS request, if I want to get the map of, lets say, December 1985, I send parameters like this:

```
...&env=year:1985;month:12&...
```

I think there is a mistake in the Geoserver online user manual, where is said:

```
...&env=name1:value1;name2=value2&...
```

Instead it should be:

```
...&env=name1:value1;name2:value2&...
```

Comment: Where is the difference for the last 2 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

It's work!
I request: GetMap and env param ..&env:myCol:population;break_1:75.79;..&..

`<ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
    <!--I try this-->
    <ogc:Function name="property">
      <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>myCol</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
    <!--Instead of this-->
    <!--<ogc:PropertyName>c01</ogc:PropertyName>-->
    <ogc:Function name="env">
      <ogc:Literal>break_1</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
</ogc:Filter>`

Answer (score -1):

Post:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/LPDB/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=LPDB:lpdb_test_polygon&&env=color:40e0d0;opacity:1;&styles=&bbox=31.302,29.9575,31.3153,29.9621&width=954&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

SLD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Simple polygon with stroke</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>SLD Cook Book: Simple polygon with stroke</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">
                #<ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>FF0000</ogc:Literal>
               </ogc:Function>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>opacity</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
               </ogc:Function>            
              </CssParameter>
            </Fill>

            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```